# Remote desktop to Win2k3 server starts new session

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2003

I use RD to connect to a number of remote servers over a VPN.  This VPN can sometime drop out unexpectedly and then it seems to be a lottery as to whether I can connect back to the same RD session I was on or a new one.  Every time this happens I can view the sessions in Task Manager and see that there are 2 running for my hostname however I don't know how to get back into the original one.  Is there a way to specify a particular session to connect to?

I have tried connecting once to fill up the remaining RD slot and then connecting again however it then just gives me the 'Terminal server has reached it's maximum connections' message rather than letting me choose one to resume.  I don't want to have to use /admin.

Is it possible to connect to a particular session?

Comment: This may be better suited for serverfault.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said you can see the other sessions in `Task Manager`, have you tried right clicking and choosing the `Connect` option?

[image]

Comment: +1 Try connecting to the console session i.e. launch mstsc with /console option (mstsc /console). This will make you connect to session 0 always.

Comment: I'm just off to connect to my session, and then hang my head in shame.  Can't believe I didn't figure that out!

@Ganesh R - I wanted to keep session 0 clear as access is needed to the sever by network support who will always use that

Comment: awesome, even a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

If windows doesn't see the session as actually being disconnected then a new session will be created.  If you attempt to re-connect fast enough after a session has been dropped you may get to a new session.

If you fire up the terminal server manager in the new session and disconnect (not reset) the session, logout, and login again, you should get to your old session.